# Collection with FIFO retrieval

Tags: data-structures, collections, linked-list

GRE CS: Which data structure would be most appropriate to implement a collection of values with the following three characteristics?

- Items are retrieved and removed from the collection in `FIFO`
- There is no a-priori limit on the number of items in the
  collection.
- The size of an item is large relative to the storage
  required for a memory address.

This was a multiple-choice question with these answers:

- (A) Singly-linked list, with head and tail pointers
- (B) Doubly-linked list, with only a head pointer
- (C) Array
- (D) Binary tree
- (E) Hash table

I think (C), (D) and (E) are wrong.

Comment: What options have you eliminated?  This site doesn't exist to do your homework for you.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I know it's not for HW. BTW I have elimained C,D and E ..

Comment: @MikeSamuel I guess (A) is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` does seem to be the correct answer. Because items are removed in FIFO you will only ever need to operate on the first and last element in the collection. A, C and E all allow this in constant time.

There is no limit on the number of items. This means that C and E are no longer as good as A because you will eventually need to re-size an array or hash table as it gets large or allocate far more than you need to start. With a linked list you can easily add as you go.

The size of an item is large. This only further goes to suggest that A is correct because the addition of the link addresses in the storage structure will be unimportant.